# Web api 2 - Async Post

Tags: post, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I'm develop a web api2 where I post json data.

The code of this api is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(an_lavanderie an_lavanderie)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new Exception("modello non valido"));
    }

    bool creato = _repoLavanderie.CreaLavanderia(an_lavanderie);

    if (creato == true)
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new Exception("Errore nella creazione"));
    }
    return response;
}
```

This code write into db correctly.
My code to POST DATA is this:

```
var risultato = PostDataAsync();

and the function is

var lav1 = new Lavanderia()
{
    rag_soc = "Ragione Sociale",
    rag_soc2 = "Ragione sociale2",
    indirizzo = "Via Crispi 27",
    citta = "Ovada",
    provincia = "AL",
    isAttiva = "N",
    portalkey = "sample string 1",
    isPortalVisibile = "S",
    cap = "15057"

};

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56040/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/CreaLavanderia", lav1);
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Crezione effettuata correttamente");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Creazione non effettuata");
    }
}
return "";
```

Post operation is ok, but when await don't fire.
Is possible that the return Message from webapi is not correct? 
Where is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What results do you get when you follow a POST in your browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using await and you're saying that it's not firing make sure that your method is marked with the keyword async.

Comment: Hi, The PostDataAsync() is public async Task<string> PostDataAsync()  . The  PostAsJsonAsync() call web api correctly.